# Combining shell commands with :terminal

Tags: command-line

I have two shell commands which I want to run. However I only want to run the second one if the first one was successful.
For simplicity let the commands be `ls` and `ls`.
I can call then once at a time manually, no problem.

```
:terminal ls
Home Documents ...
:terminal ls
Home Documents ...
```

But if I combine them, it breaks completely.

```
:terminal ls && ls
ls: cannot access '&&': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'ls': No such file or directory
```

From the buffer name it looks like it is calling `:!ls && ls` as it should.
However `!ls && ls` gives the desired result for me, and `:terminal ls && ls` doesn't.

Can anybody explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a shell to parse &&.

try `:terminal bash -c "ls && ls"`

without a shell `ls` will see all the arguments, including && and ls and will hence fail